# Cannot run PythonScript task in Azure Pipelines

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a Python script I am testing in Azure pipelines that works fine if I edit the yaml file to be:
 `- script: python Directory/test_script.py`
I would like to run it using the PythonScript task because I need to pass arguments into the script and that doesn't seem to be supported using just the  `- script` method.
My yaml file contains:

```
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'filePath' 
    scriptPath: python Directory/test_script.py 
    arguments: --hello world
```

When the pipeline executes it shows the following error:
`##[error]ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/vsts/work/1/s/python`
How can I get the script to execute correctly so I can input parameters? I've also tried changing the `workingDirectory` parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to run python script you can use for instance [`Python Script`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/python-script?view=azure-devops) task:

```yaml
steps:
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'filePath' # Options: filePath, inline
    scriptPath: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/stackoverflow/45/script.py # Required when scriptSource == filePath
    #script: # Required when scriptSource == inline
    #arguments: # Optional
    #pythonInterpreter: # Optional
    #workingDirectory: # Optional
    #failOnStderr: false # Optional
- bash: python $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/stackoverflow/45/script.py
- script: python $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/stackoverflow/45/script.py
```

Your mistake is putting python here `scriptPath: python Directory/test_script.py`. This should have only path to script but you also put here `python`, so agent tries to find folder python.